# PANDAS: Wrong column names while importing data from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import-from-csv

I am getting Wrong column names by this code: 
Why is this happening? Is there any other way to do this?

```
names = {'SYMBOL','CLMP'}
data2 = pd.read_csv(filePath +"\\"+ fileNameCM2+'.csv',skiprows = 1, index_col=False, names = names,header=None)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

print(df3.head())

OUTPUT:
          CLMP    SYMBOL
0         ACC    853921
1    ADANIENT   2758466
2  ADANIPORTS   7591819
3  ADANIPOWER  11774513
4  AJANTPHARM    257752

EXPECTED:
      SYMBOL      CLMP
0         ACC    853921
1    ADANIENT   2758466
2  ADANIPORTS   7591819
3  ADANIPOWER  11774513
4  AJANTPHARM    257752
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `set` will sort the names, instead use a `list` of columns names:

```
names = ['SYMBOL','CLMP']
df3 = pd.read_csv(filePath +"\\"+ fileNameCM2+'.csv',
                  skiprows = 1, 
                  index_col=False, 
                  names = names)

print (df)
       SYMBOL      CLMP
0         ACC    853921
1    ADANIENT   2758466
2  ADANIPORTS   7591819
3  ADANIPOWER  11774513
4  AJANTPHARM    257752
```

Comment: Yes working fine, but what was {'SYMBOL','CLMP'} this doing?

Comment: I think it is `set`, so order should be changed.

Comment: I thought OP was trying to sort the columns giving the names, didn't realise he was trying to change the names